# how to fix getDataTask method error?

Tags: android

below is my code there is a problem some where in  getDataTask if i remove this class is work fine and print Toast message      Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); but what is problem in my  getDataTask im parsing below json file   problem is some where in doinbackground method  help me please

```
 {"status":0,"message":"No such school found"}



           public class thirdstep extends Activity {


ListView listCategory;

String status;
String message;
String MenuSelect;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
long Cat_ID;
String Cat_name;

String CategoryAPI;
int IOConnect = 0;
TextView txtAlert;
thirdstepAdapter cla;
static ArrayList<String> Category_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category_list2);
    ImageButton btnback = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnback);
    listCategory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCategory2);
       prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
       txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);
    cla = new thirdstepAdapter(thirdstep.this);

    new getDataTask().execute();

    listCategory.setAdapter(cla);

    btnback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

    {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    Intent iGet = getIntent();
    Cat_ID = iGet.getLongExtra("category_id", 0);
    Cat_name = iGet.getStringExtra("category_name");

    Toast.makeText(this, Cat_ID + Cat_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    MenuSelect = Utils.MenuSelect;

    listCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(thirdstep.this,   fourthscreen.class);


            iMenuList.putExtra("Cat_ID",Cat_ID);
            iMenuList.putExtra("Menuitem", Category_ID.get(position));


            startActivity(iMenuList);

        }
    });



}

void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();
}





 public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        getDataTask(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
            }
        }

        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parseJSONData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
            if((Category_ID.size() > 0) || IOConnect == 0){
                listCategory.setVisibility(0);
                listCategory.setAdapter(cla);
            }else{
                txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
            }
        }
    }

public void parseJSONData() {


    CategoryAPI = Utils.MenuList + Cat_ID;

    clearData();
    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(CategoryAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);

        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);


        status = json2.getString("status");
        message = json2.getString("message");

        if (status.equals("1")) {

        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        JSONArray school = data.getJSONArray("menu_groups");




        for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);

            Category_ID.add(object.getString("id"));
            Category_name.add(object.getString("title"));
            Category_image.add(object.getString("image"));

        }

        }
        else    
        {

            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error. does it crash?

Comment: can you post the stack trace pls

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `parseJSONData()` in doInbackground and you have this

```
  Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // in parseJSONData()
```

you cannot update ui from `doInbackground`. You need to update ui on the ui thread. Return result in `doInbackground`. In `onPostExecute` update ui.

Comment: @user2659385 `doInbackground` in invoked on the background thread. You cannot update ui from it. You are displaying toast which should be done on ui thread. What is it that you don't understand. And pls post the stacktrace for further assistance

Comment: or you can use a handler to allow updating of UI from a non-UI thread

Comment: can u please edit my code ??? what ur saying how to update non UI thread for UI????

Comment: @user2659385 go read asynctask docs especially the topic under the section The 4 steps http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.  comment out the toast part and you still haven't posted stacktrace