# how to show toast in getDataTaskmethod?

Tags: android

this is my code below which work perfectly only  problem is  not show toast mesage code is blast i want to display toast mesage if Status is 0  in this line  if (status.equals("1")) 
 show toast message but code is blast if i comment Toast then code run perfectly help me what do  i do??

```
        public class thirdstep extends Activity {


ListView listCategory;

String status;
String message;
String MenuSelect;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
long Cat_ID;
String Cat_name;

String CategoryAPI;
int IOConnect = 0;
TextView txtAlert;
thirdstepAdapter cla;
static ArrayList<String> Category_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category_list2);
    ImageButton btnback = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnback);
    listCategory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCategory2);
       prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
       txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);
    cla = new thirdstepAdapter(thirdstep.this);

    new getDataTask().execute();

    listCategory.setAdapter(cla);

    btnback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

    {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    Intent iGet = getIntent();
    Cat_ID = iGet.getLongExtra("category_id", 0);
    Cat_name = iGet.getStringExtra("category_name");

    Toast.makeText(this, Cat_ID + Cat_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    MenuSelect = Utils.MenuSelect;

    listCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(thirdstep.this,   
                      fourthscreen.class);


            iMenuList.putExtra("Cat_ID",Cat_ID);
            iMenuList.putExtra("Menuitem", Category_ID.get(position));


            startActivity(iMenuList);

        }
    });



}

void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();
}





 public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        getDataTask(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
            }
        }

        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parseJSONData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
            if((Category_ID.size() > 0) || IOConnect == 0){
                listCategory.setVisibility(0);
                listCategory.setAdapter(cla);
            }else{
                txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
            }
        }
    }

public void parseJSONData() {


    CategoryAPI = Utils.MenuList + Cat_ID;

    clearData();
    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(CategoryAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);

        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);


        status = json2.getString("status");
        message = json2.getString("message");

        if (status.equals("1")) {

        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        JSONArray school = data.getJSONArray("menu_groups");




        for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);

            Category_ID.add(object.getString("id"));
            Category_name.add(object.getString("title"));
            Category_image.add(object.getString("image"));

        }

        }
        else    
        {

            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: Did you try to put Log if it reaches to else statement?

Comment: Try passing getBaseContext() instead of `this`

Comment: how?  give example? or edit my code please

Comment: getBaseContext()   not works

Comment: Any way related to user2659385 who asked a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211041/how-to-fix-getdatatask-method-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your toast message is within the parseJsonData method which is called from the doInBackground method of your asynctask.

You can not update the user interface thread from a background thread.

You have two options here

1) You can publish the progress `publishProgress(1)` of the thread passing in an integer value to be used as a flag which you can pick up on in the onPublishProgress listener and show your toast there

or

2) As your method has finished by this point then make the `parseJsonData` set an integer variable global to the asynctask and in the `onPostExecute` method pass something back to the listener to indicate that  a toast needs to be shown

**Update based on comments**

Replace

```
  {
      Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

with

```
  {
      publishProgress(1);
  }
```

Add the missing onProgressUpdate() method to your asynctask

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... percent) {
  //Call your listeners.onProgressUpdate(percent) here and show the
  //Or
  super.onProgressUpdate(percent);
  if (percent[0] == 1){
     Toast.makeText(thirdstep.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

I'm not here to write your code for you. Do some research on how to properly write an async task and publish progress

Here is a good starting point
http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

You should be aware of orientation changes and how that will effect your asynctask (I avoid the pitfals of this by using a fragment

This is the design pattern I use for async tasks
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

But for handling web services, be nice to your users and let the android system work out when to download data etc and don't drain their battery and use a sync adapter with an intentservice instead of an asynctask. There are already too many crappy apps out there that take the asynctask approach for consuming web services. Please don't add yours to the list

Do it this way
http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

It's a lot of extra learning curve but your a programmer right? You should be giving your users the best possible experience.

BTW You are getting down votes because you are demanding code to be written for you. I'm hoping this is just a language barrier and not an attitude problem.

Comment: not theory give me pratical soluton please

Comment: @user2644835 That was a practical solution. Just make a call to publishProgress(). I gave you two solutions. There is no need at all to use the runOnUIthread. Whilst it works it's the wrong solution for an AsyncTask and teaches you nothing about how to properly use an AsyncTask

Comment: u mean ur solutiion is more professional??

Comment: do me little favour can u edit my code according to ur solution which u say in words?? please

Comment: ur right if id is 0 screen not goes back to previous

Answer (score 0):

Surround your Toast with this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes thts work you are nice programmer